How to force plotly select to brush along the x-axis only
I am trying to combine plotly interactivity with shiny:
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)

by brushing with constant mouse movement, the selection is correct with x and y axis like this:

However, if user hand moved up or down, the selection box will get compromised ending in undesirable selection.

I want to force the first way of selection (everything along x-axis).
Any help is appreciated.

We can set dragmode = 'select' and selectdirection = 'h' in layout() to achive this:
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length) |> layout(dragmode = 'select', selectdirection = 'h')

Please run
library(listviewer)
plotly::schema()

and navigate:
layout -> layoutAttributes -> selectdirection
for further information.

When dragmode is set to select, this limits the selection of the drag to
horizontal, vertical or diagonal. h only allows horizontal selection, v
only vertical, d only diagonal and any sets no limit.

